# Chrome shows small boxes when typing in Arabic

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

[image]

When I type in Arabic language it show small boxes.
Anybody can help solving this?

Comment: That's a font issue. The text is there, but the font it's being displayed in doesn't have glyphs for those characters. Either use a different font, or look into installing a new font that has Arabic characters. I haven't used Windows-10, but older versions of Windows had optional language packs you could install to allow displaying and typing in other languages. Look for an Arabic language pack, probably in the same area where you control system updates.

Comment: i did what you said but still not working , this happens in chrome , any more help

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 ships with minimal language support, unlike earlier Windows versions.

To add Language Packs, type 'Language Packs' into the Search bar, hit Enter, then click the Add button under Languages.

[image]